# Limit of $y=f(x)=\frac{3x-e^{\sin x}}{5+e^{-x}-\cos x}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have the following function:

$$
y=f(x)=\frac{3x-e^{\sin x}}{5+e^{-x}-\cos x}
$$

Which is the limit when $x \to \pm \infty$. May you explain why?

Comment: Here's a small thing i would like to bring to your notice. e raised to sin x is a bounded function, even for x tending to infinity you can put bounds on it.

Comment: This is an exam test for the italian state exam, going on now (21 june 2018). Should be closed until tomorrow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $x$ goes to $+\infty$, the numerator goes to $+\infty$ whereas the denominator is bounded (and remain in, say, $[3,7]$). Hence, the function goes to $+\infty$.

When $x$ goes to $-\infty$, the numerator is equivalent to $3x$ whereas the denominator is equivalent to $e^{-x}$. Hence, your function has the same limit as $\frac{3x}{e^{-x}}=3xe^x$ at $-\infty$, that is $0$.

Comment: To make  the second  case more rigourous, you might add that $\; 3x=o(\mathrm e^{-x})$ near $-\infty$ (+1).